# How can you choose a line that fulfills all the conditions?

Tags: c#, ado.net

**How do we know the number of common values between two lines from two different tables? using csharp.**

```
table1.row[1]={5,6,3,4,1}

 table2.row[3]={6,4,16,18,7,'2'}
```

*// table2.row[3][5] is char mean number of duplicate value must be to return true (i make it char because i dont want program use this
value whenthey do comparison)//*

**in this two table the funcion need to return true
because we have two duplicate number and its the same value given by user in  table2.row[3][5]**

Comment: There are a few ways to achieve this. Share what you have you tried.

Comment: i m looking for how i can because i have in the first table all posbilty of 5 number betwen 1 and 25
and the second table i have users  that try to know the correct one the admin can say just how manny number correct you have  and you need to know what are the right 5 number in admin of game mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to find duplicates.

Here's one that doe not use anything C# specific.

```
var a = new [] {5,2,3,4,1};
var b = new [] {2,4,16,18,'2'};


List<object> commonElements =  new(); // You can also just count 'duplicates'
for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)    
        if(b[j] == a[i]) 
        {   
            commonElements.Add(a[i]); 
            break;
        }
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",commonElements));
```

This prints `2,4`.

Later you can

```
if(commonElements.Count == user_input)
{
    ...
}
```

BTW. Please note that `'2'` and `2` would not be considered the same.

Comment: can i give you the whole  probleme ?

Comment: Our game sequencer picks  five rondom  number between 1 and 25 ex( 5 4 12 6 24 ). Players give answers by giving five numbers and the game sequencer tells you how many correct numbers you have.
For example, the set of numbers chosen by the organizer is 3 5 17 18 12. (He will not tell anyone about it)

Comment: The players will answer each person for example the first player said 2 4 3 7 12 The organizer will answer him that you have one correct number(in this case12) . And so on, from the previous results, we deduce the correct answer. The first to reach it wins. I want to create a program for this game that i give to the programe  the answers of participants and the number of correct numbers in each answer, and it deduces the  five correct numbers that fulfill all these conditions.

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework, so I'm sorry, but I cannot help you with this.

Comment: not a homework i have the algorithm in my mind i have problem in programing its a game   i can write all algorithm but i dont have programing tools good

Comment: i find a function in python that say  "if number in row " 
if this function are in c# that can will be easy

Comment: i will tell you the algorithm 
i will create a table  withh all possibilty of 1-25 combinision 
then what i need is an interface  with csharp with 6 textbox  5 for number given and sex one for how many corect number 
then the function will go to the first table and do for each row  wi will count how many duplicate number if not egal given number must delete this line